# SQL Data not showing data for certain date ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I am having some issues with getting dates showing up in my query when I changed the dates in my variable, below is what I have declared.

```
declare @record int;
declare @start_date date;
declare @end_date date;

set @record = 2;
set @start_date =   '2016-03-01';
set @end_date =     '2016-03-31';
```

What I have created is temp tables which populate my data by Date ranges. The dates are set up as below

```
 - Daily 2016-01-15 
- weekly 2016-51 
- Monthly 2016-04 
- Quarterly 2016-01
- Yearly 2016
```

So when I declare the dates above and filter by yearly I should get data back, in fact no matter what date I put in for yearly I should get results but nothing is showing up.

When I declare the start date = 2016-01-01 it returns data for everything I filter by.

Can anybody offer some advice on a way to fix this problem I have no idea.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your query? How do you use `Yearly` in your `where`/`join` or whatever filtering option you've got?

Comment: If you don't show the rest of the script, how can we help?

Comment: I've removed the mySql tag based on the tSql tag. Please use relevant tags only.

Comment: show the query! it's unsalveagable right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is your query which is not working, but the basic isead sould be like that:

```
select * from YourTempTable where datepart (yy, DateField) = datepart(yy, @start_date)
```

of course this is not optimal for big tables as it wouldn't use any index.

Better would be to construct a @DateFrom and @DateTo variables based on the period you are looking for and the reference dates described above and make your select accordingly:

```
select * from YourTempTable where DateField between = @DateFrom and @DateTo
```